# Are supersonic passenger aircraft still realistic?

Tags: airliner, supersonic

I was wondering if supersonic passenger aircraft like Concorde or the Tupolev Tu 144 can still be made and flown profitably. The Tu 144 failed because it was poorly designed. And Concord failed because of its high profile crash.

After these, what are chances of supersonic passenger aircraft coming back? One popular news I heard was of boom supersonic jet https://boomsupersonic.com.

Comment: The Concorde was on its way out well before the crash, it just helped speed along the inevitable.

Comment: Perhaps you should change "still" to "ever".  I think both the Concorde and Tupolev were much more about technical chauvinism than about practical economics.